# Pandas dataframe being treated as a series object after using groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I am conducting an analysis of a dataset. To find my results, I use this line of code:

```
new_df = df_ncis.groupby(['state', 'year'])['totals'].mean()
```

The object returned by this statement is a Series, when it should be a dataframe. I don't understand why this happened, or how to solve this issue. Also, one of the columns of the new object is missing its name.  Here is the github link for the project: https://github.com/louishrm/gundataUS.
Any help would be great.

Comment: you can reset the index: `df_ncis.groupby(['state', 'year'])['totals'].mean().reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filtering the result by `['totals']` which is a series.
try this instead

```py
new_df = df_ncis[['state', 'year', 'totals']].groupby(['state', 'year']).mean()
```

which will give you a dataframe with your 3 columns.
or if you want it as a dataframe of one column (Note the double brackets)

```
new_df = df_ncis.groupby(['state', 'year'])[['totals']].mean()
```